# How to removethe store assocation from a Windows Store app in dev environment

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to take an app that's previously been associated with a store app and distribute the source code to some peers.  I would like to revert it so its not running with a store association at all, and simply running off of the temporary key.

How do you remove a store association from an app?

Aka take it back to the point where its running off of App1.Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx  instead of ( Package.StoreAssociation.xml and App1.Windows_StoreKey.pfx ) ?  Can't quite figure out what file to edit.

I associated it with a temp key, and removed the Package.StoreAssociation as well as the App1.Windows_StoreKey.pfx files.

Even after re-associating my temporary key, it keeps wanting the Package.StoreAssociation.xml back when I compile the project, and I can't quite seem to find out where the reference is set in any files.

For example.  Download this app, then get it to run without ANY store association.  Just run off the temporary key.

https://weatherview.codeplex.com/

Thanks...